Finding a tool to detect unrequired modules in a nodejs project
I have a nodejs project which provides some API routes. I have to disable some routes in some deployments. I do this by removing the require line in my main entry file (app.js). By doing so all the branches of that 'require()' are effectively removed and turned into dead code.
Now I want the files 'required' by those routes to be deleted from the project. Theoraticaly it can be done by finding the files that are not required anywhere. Maybe by starting from the app.js and create a tree using the required files and then remove the files that are not in the tree. In other word a textual scan can find the files that are not required.
I am having a hard time finding a tool to do such work.

It's unknown what's your case. You can use inspections in jetbrains ides to find unused code, not sure how it would be usable to get a list of unused modules. But this applies to ES modules, for CJS this would be different because are less efficient or impossible to analyze if you use dynamic module names. But for CJS you can extract effectively used modules from require.cache at runtime

It is CJS by the way.

Then the comment regarding CJS applies here, console.log of require.cache inside a timeout will give you a real picture

As I said I just need a textual check. I don't need to see which modules were required in practice.

You need to extract module paths from the list and compare with the list of file paths from the repo. The diff will be what you ask for

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const allJsFiles = new Set()
function getRequiredModules(directory) {
  const modulePaths = new Set()

  function traverseDirectory(dir) {
    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
      const filePath = path.join(dir, file)
      const stat = fs.statSync(filePath)

      if (stat.isDirectory()) {
        traverseDirectory(filePath)
      } else if (file.endsWith('.js')) {
        extractRequiredModules(filePath, modulePaths)
      }
    })
  }

  traverseDirectory(directory)
  return Array.from(modulePaths).filter(modulePath => !modulePath.startsWith('node_modules/'))
}

function extractRequiredModules(filePath, modulePaths) {
  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8')
  const regex = /require\(['"](.*?)['"]/g

  let match
  while ((match = regex.exec(fileContent)) !== null) {
    let moduleName = match[1]
    try {
      // console.log('prepath', filePath, moduleName)
      if (moduleName.startsWith('.') || moduleName.startsWith('..') || moduleName.startsWith('/')) {
        moduleName = path.join(path.dirname(filePath), moduleName)
        //   console.log('mo joined ' , moduleName)
        let stat
        try {
          stat = fs.statSync(moduleName)
        } catch (e) { moduleName += '.js' }

        if (stat?.isDirectory()) {
          moduleName += '/index.js'
        }
        allJsFiles.add(filePath)
        moduleName = './' + moduleName
      }

      const modulePath = require.resolve(moduleName)

      const relativePath = path.relative(process.cwd(), modulePath)
      modulePaths.add(relativePath)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
}

// usage:
const projectRoot = './src' // replace with your project root directory
const requiredModules = getRequiredModules(projectRoot)

console.log('unused', [...allJsFiles].filter(f => !requiredModules.includes(f)))

That is what I came up with.

Can you comment on why you chose this approach? Because module cache already contains this data. Object.keys(require.cache) is the list of required modules at the time of calling

require.cache keeps the modules required during code execution. So if a require is inside a function that is not called yet or is conditionally called then it wouldn't be in the cache. Also you have to have environment ready an be able to run the app which is not always the case in a CI/CD for example.

I see. Yes, this requires all modules to be imported roughly on app initialization. This would would suit most server side apps, lazy loading is more a feature for client side. Notice that a regex cannot handle dynamic module names, as mentioned above
